# How to render render code block from values file in helm charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I've a block in `values.yaml` like

```
extraHosts:
- hosts:
  - domain1.tld
  port:
    name: sftp
    number: 22
    protocol: TCP
- hosts:
  - domain2.tld
  port:
    name: sftp
    number: 2222
    protocol: TCP
```

I want to template this whole block like

```
servers:
- hosts:
  - domain1.tld
  port:
    name: sftp
    number: 22
    protocol: TCP
- hosts:
  - domain2.tld
  port:
    name: sftp
    number: 2222
    protocol: TCP
```

I tried

```
servers:
{{- range .Values.extraHosts }}
- {{ . }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helm has an undocumented `toYaml` function that can dump out an object from `.Values` as valid YAML.

```yaml
servers:
{{ toYaml .Values.extraHosts | indent 2 }}
```

(In this example the `indent` isn't strictly necessary; if the object was a map rather than a list then it would be.)